# How do I replace front-end views with JSONs in Codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a **blog application** with **Codeigniter 3.1.8**.

Currently, its admin area is well separated from the frontend. Both the *backend* (admin area) and the *frontend* display data using "classic" Codeigniter views.

I thought It would be great if I could replace the classic views *of the frontend* with **JSONS** so that they could be formated and displayed using *frontend technologies* like Vue or Angular, independently of the classic Codeigniter views, that I would only use on the backend.

The JSONS should be spat out directly from the controllers involved in the functioning of the posts and single post pages, *without the help of the views*.

I need a reliable method for this, as the controllers are quite complex. Here is the **Posts** controller:

```
class Posts extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    private function _initPagination($path, $totalRows, $query_string_segment = 'page') {
    //load and configure pagination 
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = base_url($path);
        $config['query_string_segment'] = $query_string_segment; 
        $config['enable_query_strings'] =TRUE;
        $config['reuse_query_string'] =TRUE;
        $config['total_rows'] = $totalRows;
        $config['per_page'] = 12;
        if (!isset($_GET[$config['query_string_segment']]) || $_GET[$config['query_string_segment']] < 1) {
            $_GET[$config['query_string_segment']] = 1;
        }
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $limit = $config['per_page'];
        $offset = ($this->input->get($config['query_string_segment']) - 1) * $limit;

        return ['limit' => $limit, 'offset' => $offset];
    }

    public function index() {

    //call initialization method
        $config = $this->_initPagination("/", $this->Posts_model->get_num_rows());

        $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
        $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
        $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();  

        //use limit and offset returned by _initPaginator method
        $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts($config['limit'], $config['offset']);
        $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('posts');
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
    }


    public function byauthor($authorid){
        $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
        $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
        $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories(); 
        $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts_by_author($authorid); 
        $data['posts_count'] = $this->Posts_model->posts_by_author_count($authorid); 
        $data['posts_author'] = $this->Posts_model->posts_author($authorid);

        $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('posts_by_author');
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
    }

    public function post($slug) {
        $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
        $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
        $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();
        $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->sidebar_posts($limit=5, $offset=0);
        $data['post'] = $this->Posts_model->get_post($slug);

        if ($data['categories']) {
            foreach ($data['categories'] as &$category) {
                $category->posts_count = $this->Posts_model->count_posts_in_category($category->id);
            }
        }

        if (!empty($data['post'])) {
            // Overwrite the default tagline with the post title
            $data['tagline'] = $data['post']->title;

            // Get post comments
            $post_id = $data['post']->id;
            $data['comments'] = $this->Comments_model->get_comments($post_id);

            $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('post');
        } else {
            $data['tagline'] = "Page not found";
            $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('404');
        }
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
    }

}
```

So, I need a rock-solid method to spit all that as JSON at once.

What is the best approach for this?

Comment: You're still going to need a view to load the js and enough DOM for the frontend tech to spit on. You will still need controllers and methods to supply as URLs to your frontend too - no?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this line of code, *instead of rendering the views*, in every method of my controller:

```
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($data));
```

This is what the controller looks like now:

```
class Posts extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    private function _initPagination($path, $totalRows, $query_string_segment = 'page') {
    //load and configure pagination 
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = base_url($path);
        $config['query_string_segment'] = $query_string_segment; 
        $config['enable_query_strings'] =TRUE;
        $config['reuse_query_string'] =TRUE;
        $config['total_rows'] = $totalRows;
        $config['per_page'] = 12;
        if (!isset($_GET[$config['query_string_segment']]) || $_GET[$config['query_string_segment']] < 1) {
            $_GET[$config['query_string_segment']] = 1;
        }
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $limit = $config['per_page'];
        $offset = ($this->input->get($config['query_string_segment']) - 1) * $limit;

        return ['limit' => $limit, 'offset' => $offset];
    }

    public function index() {

    //call initialization method
        $config = $this->_initPagination("/", $this->Posts_model->get_num_rows());

        $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
        $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
        $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();  

        //use limit and offset returned by _initPaginator method
        $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts($config['limit'], $config['offset']);

         $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($data));
    }

    public function byauthor($authorid){
        $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
        $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
        $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories(); 
        $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts_by_author($authorid); 
        $data['posts_count'] = $this->Posts_model->posts_by_author_count($authorid); 
        $data['posts_author'] = $this->Posts_model->posts_author($authorid);

        $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($data));
    }

    public function post($slug) {
        $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
        $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
        $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();
        $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->sidebar_posts($limit=5, $offset=0);
        $data['post'] = $this->Posts_model->get_post($slug);

        if ($data['categories']) {
            foreach ($data['categories'] as &$category) {
                $category->posts_count = $this->Posts_model->count_posts_in_category($category->id);
            }
        }

        if (!empty($data['post'])) {
            // Overwrite the default tagline with the post title
            $data['tagline'] = $data['post']->title;

            // Get post comments
            $post_id = $data['post']->id;
            $data['comments'] = $this->Comments_model->get_comments($post_id);

             $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($data));
        } else {
            $data['tagline'] = "Page not found";
             $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($data));
        }
         $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($data));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried simply encode it with native php? or what is the issue here?

i'd do it like this:

```
$data['json']=json_encode($data);
```

so you can use  $json in the view.

… and eventually JSON.parse in the JS frontend then.

Comment: I would have to use that in _every method_ of _at least two controllers_ and I would rather not.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in your controller for echoing json output

```
public $json = array();

public function render_json()
{
    $this->output
    ->set_status_header(200)
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output(json_encode( $this->json ));
}
```

and in any method inside your controller just append to `$this->json` array:

```
$this->json['key'] = 'value';
```

then render:

```
$this->render_json();
```

Btw if you wanna use it globally, just move it to a base controller.

---

**Example**

```
public function fetch()
{
    $this->json['key'] = 'value';
    $this->render_json();
}
```

now when you call this method via ajax it would give you a json object with whatever was in `$this->json` array, in js:

```
.done(function( response ) {
    console.log(response.key); // = value
});
```

Comment: I do not have a base controller

Comment: Should `$this->render_json();` be placed in a/the view?

Comment: You should create a base controller anyways to eliminate redundancy and keep it DRY .. for `$this->render_json();` place it at the end of your method it would work echoing the results.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir .. see the edits, i hope its clear now!

Comment: Within the context of my `Posts` controller, how would you renter the _list of posts_ as JSON?

Comment: You need to keep `index` method as it is to load the view but move the logic of fetching `posts` to another method and assign it to `json` object like this `$this->json['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts($config['limit'], $config['offset']);` then call `$this->render_json();` after that .. and call this method via ajax and in the response you get the posts as json.